# The result of makefile execution is different from shell execution

Tags: macos, shell, makefile

my Makefile:

```
foo:
    echo -n "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "1@123456"
```

when I run: `make foo`, the output is different from the result of running the same command directly on the shell.(mac m2 arm64)

```
MacBook-Air:tmp $ make foo
echo -n "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "1@123456"
b6977416b3597483a9e416f4c04a1dcd
MacBook-Air:tmp$ echo -n "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "1@123456"
44ac6a36a27b1e5352a14e803929516f
```

But when I execute the same operation in an amd64 Ubuntu environment, the results are consistent.

```
tmp$ make foo
echo -n "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "1@123456"
MD5(stdin)= 44ac6a36a27b1e5352a14e803929516f
echo -n "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "1@123456"
MD5(stdin)= 44ac6a36a27b1e5352a14e803929516f
```

I am grateful for your guidance.

Comment: Please don't use images of text. Just copy and paste the text itself into the answer as a code block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion on how to ask questions! I will keep this in mind for future questions. @MarkReed

Comment: when I add `SHELL := /bin/zsh`, the problem was resolved

Comment: Use printf instead of echo and never look back.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like `printf` is a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `echo` command is built into the shell, so its behavior depends upon that shell, which is different between platforms. And `make` by default runs `/bin/sh` rather than whatever `$SHELL` is set to in the environment.

If you remove the `openssl` command you can see the behavior difference clearly - the `sh` echo on macOS doesn't understand `-n` as an option, but just includes it in the output¹. You can reproduce the behavior like so:

```
 $ /bin/sh -c 'echo -n d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
 -n d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

(A complicating factor is that `make` tries to be smart about when it needs the shell and when it can get away with just `exec()`ing the command directly - so a plain `echo` with no pipe may do the latter and wind up running `/bin/echo`, which even on a Mac understands `-n` just fine. But any complications to the command will result in it being run by the shell.)

You could set `SHELL` inside the `Makefile`, but that introduces its own set of portability problems; if you set it to `/bin/zsh`, for instance, the Makefile won't run on systems that don't have `zsh` installed, or have it in installed in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

I would change the `echo -n` to `printf`; that way it's consistent across shells, and `printf` already doesn't append a newline. In fact, it's probably a good idea to just forget `echo` exists and always use `printf` instead (just with a `\n` on the end when you *do* want the newline).

But if you'd rather set `SHELL`, I would do so with something like this:

```
SHELL := $(shell echo "$$SHELL")
```

That tells `make` to use whatever the environment variable is set to, which will normally be what the calling shell is.

¹ <sup><sub>The Bash 3.2 that ships with macOS changes its `echo` behavior when invoked as `sh`.  Newer versions have stopped doing that, even with POSIXLY_CORRECT set, because while the POSIX standard specifies that `echo` shouldn't recognize `-n`, it also straight up admits `echo` is non-portable and says that it should be avoided except in unambiguous cases – i.e. you want to echo things literally and add a newline and there are no arguments that look like options or backslash escapes.</sub></sup>